# Google Place API Reviews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-places-api

I am working on swift app,In this I need to show reviews as shown on google, Is it possible to get more than 5 reviews from google place api. I used this api to get place details

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid="XXX"&key="XXX"

Thanks

Comment: Asking for an API recommendation is off-topic.

Comment: @Lexi I don't think this is off-topic , As I just ask for any suggestion.

Comment: Any opinion-based question is off-topic. There is a flag option that states "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." So asking for "any suggestion" is probably off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Being able to retrieve all the reviews for a given business is only supported if you are a verified business owner and can be done via the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/)

You can request access to this API by filling in a form on [this](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs) page

If you have general questions about Google My Business check out the [product forum](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/bd-p/gmb-api)

Source : [Issue 7630](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957)

Comment: Thanks @Hooda , I also get this

Comment: If it helped out, please contribute.